# Coset space of Lie group and equivalent class [gg']

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups

I read Geometry,Topology and Physics of Mikio Nakahara and ther one proof that I don't understand:
After define what's the coset space for a Lie group G and a Lie subgroup H G/H with equivalent class for $g\in G$, $[g] = \left\{gh|h\in H\right\}$, there is a proof of the "product" of equivalent class is the equivalent class of the "product" og group elements : $[g][g'] = [gg']$. The proof given is as it's follow :
$gh$, $g'h'$ the representatives of $[g]$ and $[g']$ so we have  $[g][g'] = ghg'h'=gg'h''h'$ since there exist $h''$ such as $hg'=g'h''$. This last affirmation is propably trivial but it's not clear for me... Is anyone who can clarify it? Thanks

Comment: That doesn't make sense for a general subgroup. Are you sure that the author is not assuming that $H$ is a *normal* subgroup of $G$?

Comment: In the same paragraph the concept of normal subgroup seems to be just mentionned by the sentence "G/H is a Lie group if H is a normal subgroup of G, that is, if ghg−1 ∈ H for any g ∈ G and h ∈ H." But if I understand well the demonstration is taking in general case and not just in the case of H normal subgroup... But is the property $[g][g']=[gg']$ general or just in case of H normal?

Comment: If you understood the demonstration well, you would not be posting this question here, would you? The author **is** assuming that $H$ is a normal subgroup. But, since you do not believe in this, I will wast no more time.

Comment: No need to be aggressive. Sure I don't understand well the demonstration : a comma maybe clarify my sentence : "But if I understand well, the demonstration is taking in general case and not just in the case of H normal subgroup... ' I'm talking about understanding well the text sourround the proof !!! It's why I ask you if the property is true in all case or just in the case of H normal subgroup !!!! (because if you said the property is true only if H is a normal subgroup I believe you, you're mathematician not me)... Thank you anyway

Comment: Yes, it holds only if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: This is a result about general groups, not Lie groups: if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $G/H$ with the law $[g][g'] = [gg']$ is a group if and only if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.